# Generating a random, uniformly distributed real number in C

Tags: c, double, random, uniform-distribution

I would like to generate a random, real number in the interval [0,1].
I would like to set a pointer, say `n`, for the number so whenever I stated `n`, it will be referred to the random generated number.

I have searched on StackOverflow and on Google, but most of them are for C++ or for integers.

I have tried this code suggested to me in the answers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 double n;
double get_random() { return (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX; }
n = get_random();
printf("%f", n);
   return 0;
}
```

However, I can only get a value 0.00000000.

How could I fix my program?

Comment: Does your compiler complain when you try to `printf` an `unsigned int` using `%f`?  Perhaps you meant to declare `r` as a `double` instead.

Comment: Your `while` loop is ineffective, since `y = RAND_MAX + 1` the return value from `rand` will always be `< y`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "I would like to set a pointer, say n, for the number so whenever I stated n, it will be referred to the random generated number"?  How is this not just a simple pointer assignment?

Comment: You can scale the unsigned `rand` value to a real number in your range, but the values will not be uniformly distributed as you requested. The granularity is still the same: only `RAND_MAX` different values will be generated.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear...
I am a beginner for C programming, so I just go google and found the rand() command...

Comment: e0k: Thanks for your reply. What i mean is to define a double n, where n is equal to the randomly generated number from 0 to 1.

Comment: Weather Vane : Thanks for your reply. How can I actually control the range of the rand()? I tried to type in the range inside the () or follow the instruction from the C FAQ centre, typing them after the rand() command.
However, none of them works...

Comment: I advise you to read the man page for any function that is new to you. *"The rand function returns a pseudorandom integer in the range 0 to RAND_MAX (32767). Use the srand function to seed the pseudorandom-number generator before calling rand."*. You can scale it as the answer below, where `double n` is assumed.

Comment: Thanks Weather, i will go have a look on man page.
Then i can just print the n out and see the value right?

Comment: See above comments, with `printf` you have to match the format specifier with the variable type.

Comment: Ya, I have defined and finally succeed in printing n out. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
#include <time.h>
srand(time(NULL)); // randomize seed
double get_random() { return (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX; }
n = get_random();
```

`srand()` sets the seed which is used by `rand` to generate pseudo-random numbers. If you don't call `srand` before your first call to `rand`, it's as if you had called `srand(1)` (serves as a default).

If you want to exclude [1] use:

```
(double)rand() / (double)((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1);
```

**Full solution:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double get_random() { return ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX); }

int main()
{
    double n = 0;
    srand(time(NULL)); // randomize seed
    n = get_random(); // call the function to get a different value of n every time

    printf("%f\n", n);  // print your number
    return 0;
}
```

Every time you run it you will get a different number for `n`.

Comment: Thanks Idos.
I don't know who gave the downvote though...
I still don't have the ability to upvote cause I dont have 15 reputation yet...

I did then try to print n out, but, I have tried like over tens time, and the answer is always 0.001215
Is that because the n lose it's randomness after being defined?

Comment: I will edit my answer so you can each time get a new value for n. Try it now, every time you call get_random() you will get a new different number

Comment: Idos, it is still giving 0.001215 for the result...
Should I add a ; after the {} for the definition of get_random() to make it functional?

Comment: No, that is a function... can you show exactly how you call the function? Please edit your question with that. it shouldn't give you the same number I checked it myself

Comment: You have to define your function outside the scope of main(). Let me edit my answer with a **full** solution so it will work for you

Comment: I see...
Thanks Idos, this helps me a lot...
I will try to learn more on C and the usage of function outside the main loop.... Thank you very much !

Comment: @Idos : C is a *procedural language*;  [*functional language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Functional_languages) has a specific meaning in computer science, and C is not one.

Comment: This is not uniformly distributed, and C does not provide any such implementation. There are libraries available that do, however.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to get random real numbers in the range 0..1 but please note that they are not uniformly distributed. There are only `(RAND_MAX+1)` discrete values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    double n;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));            // seed the random num generator ONCE only
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {                // get 3 random numbers
        n = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;      // in the range 0 ... 1
        printf("%f\n", n);                  // use correct format specifier for the var
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My program output:

```
0.622608
0.814081
0.878689
```